MOVIEPY - Rendering subtitles takes ABSURD amount of time
I am rendering a 1920/1080 video with an empty background and only captions. I have this placeholder code, rendering a sequence of 100 different text captions each lasting around 3.5 seconds, making the total video 6 minutes long. However, rendering it at 1 FPS, takes 2 HOURS! AT 1 FPS! And somehow, it wants to render 18,000 individual frames? Even though its only 360 seconds at 1 fps? I was hoping to render the video in 30 fps, does anyone know how to speed this process up tremendously?
text_clips = []
for text in captions:
    txt_clip = TextClip(
        text,
        fontsize=80,
        color='white',
        method="label",
    ).set_position(("center", 1900)).set_start(start_time)
    txt_clip = txt_clip.set_duration(duration)
    text_clips.append(txt_clip)

final_video = concatenate_videoclips(captions, method="compose")
final_video.fps = 1
final_video.write_videofile("captions.mp4")

I tried rendering it, and I expected it to take a few seconds to complete.
